# How do I move a commit between branches in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-cherry-pick

I'm sure this is a simple thing that has been asked and answered, but I don't know what terms to search for. I have this:

```
    /--master--X--Y
A--B
    \--C--D--E
```

Where I commited `C`, `D`, and `E` (locally only) on a branch, but then I realized that `D` and `E` are really independent of `C`. I want to move `C` to its own branch, and keep `D` and `E` for later.  That is, I want this:

```
                   /--C
    /--master--X--Y
A--B
    \--D--E
```

How do I yank `C` out from under `D` and `E`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick` to grab `C`, and put it on `Y`. Assuming `Y` exists as the tip of a branch called `branch-Y`, you can run the following commands:

```
git checkout branch-Y
git cherry-pick C
```

So now `C` is on top of `Y`. But `D` and `E` also still contain `C` (cherry-picking doesn't move a commit, it just makes a copy of it). You'll have to rebase `D` and `E` on top of `B`. Assuming `E` is the tip of `branch-E` and `B` is `branch-B`, you can run the following commands:

```
git checkout branch-E
git rebase --interactive branch-B
```

This will open up an interactive rebase session. Just remove commit `C` entirely, and leave `D` and `E` intact. You'll then have `D` and `E` rebased on top of `B` without `C`.

Comment: Note that `cherry-pick`, as of v1.7.1, can cherry-pick multiple commits, so you can use this to "yank" more than one commit out. You can also do that by creating a temporary branch at E and interactively rebasing it onto Y, keeping only the commits you want, then merging it (it'll be a fast-forward) into Y's branch. (That's always worked, and might be easier anyway, so you don't have to paste as many SHA1s.)