# How can I copy commits from one branch to another?

Tags: git

I have 4 commits in my `master` branch but I want to copy them and put into a another branch (`branch2`).

Can I do this with cherry pick and if yes how can I?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move a commit between branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710192/how-do-i-move-a-commit-between-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `cherry-pick` is what you want here. If the commits are consecutive:

```sh
git checkout branch2
git cherry-pick <commit-1-id>..<commit-4-id>
```

Otherwise you will have to specify them individually:

```sh
git cherry-pick <commit-1-id> <commit-2-id> <commit-3-id> <commit-4-id>
```