# Git - how to move commits between branches

Tags: git

I have the following:

```
branch0  ---  commit1 --- commit2 --- branch2 --- commit3
   |
branch1
   |
commit4
   |
commit5
```

I would like to change it to the following (i.e. move everything from `commit1`):

```
branch0
   |
branch1
   |
commit4
   |
commit5  ---  commit1 --- commit2 --- branch2 --- commit3
```

I have tried using `rebase` and `cherry-pick`, but I am not knowledgeable enough, so any suggestions welcome please.

Thanks

UPDATE

From mimikrija's answer below, I try the following:

```
git checkout branch0
git checkout -b temp
git rebase branch1
## fix conflicts
git add .
git commit -am "rebase applied"
git rebase --continue
git branch -mv -f branch1
```

I get the following error:

> fatal: Invalid branch name: 'HEAD'

```
git status
rebase in progress; onto 89844e6
You are currently rebasing branch 'temp' on '89844e6'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
```

Comment: This is doing something similar, but only for one commit, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710192/how-do-i-move-a-commit-between-branches-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are all local branches (not published yet, or published but not used by anyone else) these would be the steps to take.

`git checkout branch2`

`git checkout -b temp` create a temporary branch based on `branch2`

`git rebase branch1` now you have what you drew in your diagram, but it is called `temp`

`git branch -mv -f branch1` force rename the branch

and finally, remove the commits from `branch2`:

`git checkout branch2`

`git reset --hard branch0`

Comment: I am little confused, about the `branchA` and `branchB` you use. I have `branch0`, `branch1` and `branch2`. How do they correspond to those? I have those 3 branches, which each have some commits.

Comment: When I try `git branch -mv -f branch1`, I get the following: `fatal: Invalid branch name: 'HEAD'`.

Comment: @user2569831 which branch does `commit3` belong to? I was confused with your diagrams.

Comment: Sorry, if it's not too clear. I added an UPDATE to the question with the error I am getting. `commit3` belongs to `branch2`. `branch1` and `branch2` was created off `branch0`.

Comment: @user2569831 thanks for the update. Obviously you are still in a rebase (status output) which means not all the conflicts were fixed. once you have a clean `status` you may continue with renaming branches.

Comment: @user2569831 please have a look at the edited question. I think you've mixed up the branches in your rebase.

Comment: thanks for the update. Just a question, what about the `commit1` and `commit2`? I don't think they will be moved to the the `branch1`.

Comment: @user2569831 they should be there, unless the changes contained in `commit4` and `commit5` already include the same changes `commit` and `commit2` introduced. In that case,during a rebase, `commit1` and `commit2` become obsolete (they don't introduce a change) therefore they are gone. BTW to get a better understanding of this please read: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to progress on the rebase. I have resolved conflicts by doing a `git commit -am "fix conflicts from rebase"` then `git rebase --continue`, but `git status` always says `rebase in progress; onto 2636118
You are currently rebasing branch 'temp3' on '2636118'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working tree clean`.  Why can't I proceed with the `rebase`?

Comment: First of all I think you have your branches mixed up. You should be on branch `temp` and while there, run `git rebase branch1` . I am confused with the commit hash you get in the output.

Answer (score 0):

All you would need to do is to take a pull from branch 1 into branch 2

Step:

```
git checkout branch2
git pull origin branch1
```

Comment: why pull from `origin` ?

Comment: @mimikrija I was assuming the branch1 was pushed to remote and that remote is `origin`

Comment: @Shubham thanks for the reply. But I don't see how this would achieve what I need.

Comment: From what I understand, you need branch1 changes along with commit4 and commit5 in branch2 which you will get once you take a pull or branch1 in branch2