# Update commit to old branch

Tags: git

I am not too familiar with git. I have one situation.

Flow is like that =>

- I create new branch from develop
- Updated code 1

====>Forget to commit and push

====>Forget to create new branch and pull

- Update code 2 again for the new branch (But its still at old branch)

Now I am here.

How can I do

- Commit and push updated code 1 to old branch
- Create a new branch for updated code 2 and commit and push updated code 2 ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move a commit between branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710192/how-do-i-move-a-commit-between-branches-in-git)

Comment: [Create a new branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) and [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits from old to new. Then [reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) old to remove the commits you don't want

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Code 1 and Code 2 are two different files, you can do the following:

```
git add code1 // add code1 to current branch, but not code2

git commit -m "adding code1"

git push origin current-branch

git checkout -b new-branch // create new branch, you may want to move back to dev before doing that

git add code2 // add code2 to the new branch you created

git commit -m "adding code2"

git push origin new-branch
```

Finally, you will have `current-branch` with only `code1` and `new-branch` containing both `code1` and `code2`. If you move back to `dev` before creating `new-branch`, it will only contain `code2`, but not `code1`.